# Number of $n$ digit numbers that doesn't include 5 as a digit

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Given $n > 0$, where $n$ is the number of digits, how many $n$ digit numbers are there that doesn't include the number $5$?

I think this is just a combinatorics problem.

Suppose $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n$ represents the first, second, 3rd, ..., n-th digit. (By first digit I mean the most significant, so n-th digit is the ones spot).
$x_1$ has 8 choices $x_1 \in \{1,2,\ldots,4, 6, \ldots, 9\}$. $x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n$ all have $9$ choices.

So the answer appears to be $8 * 9^{n - 1}$? Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, that looks good.

Comment: @Alan What if the problem was changed to "...doesn't include 4 and/or 5?" Should it simply become $7 * 8^{n - 1}$ (i.e., each digit's number of possible values is simply reduced by 1)

Comment: Yep, with the leading digit also having the non-zero restriction

Comment: @24n8 did my answer help you ? if so , can you acept it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct and elegant ! However , if you want to see the result in another perspective  ,you can use exponential generating functions. It is very useful tool for constructing digits.

It is said that $5$ will not be used and there is not any restriction over digit. This means that any number except for $5$ can be used whatever it is wanted . Then , the exponential generating fucntion form will be $$(e^x)^9$$

To find the result of $n$ digits  ,we should find the coefficient of $e^n$ in the Taylor expansion of $e^{9x}$ , it is obviously $9^n$.

However , $9^n$ contain some strings which start with $0$ as leading term , so we must get rid of them. We can assume that the leading term is $0$ and we want to find the number of digits of lenght $(n-1)$ , by the same process , it is equalt to $9^{n-1}$.

Result ; $$9^n - 9^{n-1} = 8 \times 9^{n-1}$$

It confirms your result..